# Count records per day of all tables in Google BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I count records per day of a table by a query like:

```
SELECT
 CAST(time AS day) AS day,
 COUNT(*) AS row_per_day
FROM `dataset_id`.table_name
GROUP BY 1
```

Is there anyway workaround for all tables in a dataset? I have like 100 tables in a dataset, and not all tables have a time field.

I see the query:

```
SELECT *
FROM `dataset_id`.__TABLES__
```

But the response only includes `creation_time`, `last_modified_time`    and `row_count` (for last `modified_time`).

Comment: if a table does not have time fields, how can you identify the number of rows changed in the day?

Comment: **day** in your first query is partition column and you want to calculate rows of each daily partition for all the tables in your dataset ?  (except non-partitioned table)

Comment: @Raptor Almost tables have time (or created_at, updated_at), maybe some tables load from google sheet... dont have). Yes, if dont have time field it cant be trackable change along with time.

Comment: @Jaytiger I just find a query to select all tables in one time. Actually I just need to monitor these partitioned tables (count rows per day and save to a incremental table).

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, Bigquery has table metadata names `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PARTITIONS` which shows all information I need.
So the below query will work:

```
select *
from `dataset_id`.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PARTITIONS
```